# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.library.path\libfile.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, java.library.path

I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2 and JNI.
I have a JFrame and inside the button's actionPerformed function, I called the C++ file using the below code:
`System.loadLibrary("lib3D_Version");`

I already followed the steps to create a JNI library, but this error occurred, although, the path is correct:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.library.path\libfile.dll: Can't find dependent libraries 
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
```

Comment: Check with [Dependencies](https://lucasg.github.io/Dependencies/) what these dependent libraries are.

Comment: Thank you. But the error was fixed when I installed TDM GCC and created the c library using it.